# More products then available being purchased

Tags: expresso-store

We figured out that we have had an issue the last few weeks where products are being ordered beyond the qty available.  I was able to replicate how it was done and want to know if there is a fix.

We have our product that has 2 available total.  The product has a single SKU product modifier of size.  People have the ability of over ordering the product if they add different sizes to their cart.  For instance if their is 2 packages left and they add 2 smalls, they can go back and then add 2 more mediums to their cart and checkout.  When looking at the backend the qty is now -2 on our end.  How can we get this fixed, so far it's been on products that aren't a big deal but we do have some coming up where it would certainly would be a major issue.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of a the product in question?

Comment: Hi Cody, just to say that I've received your email and am looking in to it. Logging in I can see the problem and have been able to recreate so I'll get back to you shortly with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug - probably best if you email support@exp-resso.com so we can diagnose it and help you find a solution.